# Problem understanding analysis of greedy maximal weighted matching algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

**Greedy Algorithms for Matching**

$M = \emptyset$

For all $e \in E$ in decreasing order of $w_e$
    add $e$ to $M$ if it forms a matching

**Theorem**

The weight of the matching $M$ returned by the greedy algorithm is at least half of the weight of any matching $M^∗$.

**Proof.** Let $M^∗$ is a matching of maximum weight, and M be the matching returned by the
greedy algorithm. Note that for any edge $e \in M^∗ \setminus M$ , there is a reason $e$ didn’t get into the greedy matching $M$, a previously considered edge, lets call it $f(e)$ that has higher weight, and shares an end-node with $e$. If there are multiple such edges, let $f(e)$ be either of the two
such edges.

Note that $w_{f(e)} \leq w_e$ as we add edges in greedy order.
For an edge $f$ there can be $f(e)$ for up to at most two edges $e$, conflicting with edge $f$
at the two different ends. Putting these two facts together, we get the following inequalities
$$\sum\limits_{e\in M^{*}}w_e \geq \sum\limits_{e \in M^{*}}w_{f(e)} \geq \sum\limits_{e \in M}2w_f $$
proving the theorem.

**My comments:**
I understand that greedy algorithm makes a mistake if it takes an edge that is best by weight, but by doing so discards two edges that are adjacent to it, whose sums would contribute more two the whole sum. But i cannot understand where the factor of 2 part comes from.

Answer (score 0):

From your, proof, if we consider an edge with weight $w$ in $M*$. It has to be adjacent to another edge in $M$ with weight $w'$ such that $w' > w$. In addition, every edge in $M$ can be adjacent to at most two edges in $M*$ (one edge in each endpoint). This mean that for any edge $e' \in M$, there exists at most two $e \in M*$ such that $f(e) = e')$. For this reason we have to "divide" our bound by two and thus, the sum of the weight is at least half the optimal.